# How do I delete a certain section from a Vector?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector <string> items = {"Sword\n", "Shield\n", "Brass Helmet\n", "Iron Breastplate\n"};

void inventory(){

     for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
          cout<<items[i];
     }
}

int main(){
    inventory();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm familiar with the commands vector.pop_back() which deletes the last  in the vector, and vector.clear() which deletes the entire vector.

How would I go about deleting items[0] or deleting the portion items[0] - items[3]?

Comment: One of the `\n` characters broke containment and is running wild in your C++ source.

Comment: Tip: Don't forget the [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), as in `for (auto& i : items)` where `i` is a reference to an item. No index required.

Comment: Look up the "erase-remove-idiom".

Comment: Do you just want to ditch the first *N* entries? If so [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) has you covered.

Comment: `std::vector` provides an `erase()` method that takes begin and end iterators of the range to erase.

Comment: What prevented you from looking this up in some vector documentation?

Comment: Why are you including `\n` on each inventory item?  You should get rid of the `\n`'s in the `vector`, and then have the loop in `inventory()` output its own line break after each item, eg `cout<<items[i]<<"\n";`

Answer (score 4):

As the guys told you, you can use the erase function. You can use it to erase a specific element from the vector or delete a portion of it.

```
items.erase(items.begin());
items.erase(items.begin(), items.begin() + 3);
```

Comment: Also look at [`std::find/_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find a specific element you want to erase.